# Airflow task scheduler

Tags: airflow

My requirement is to schedule a dag task from every sunday 9 pm to Friday 9pm for every 5 min.Can any one please help me how can I achieve this.

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019,4,13,21,0),
    'email': [],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    # 'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}


dag = DAG(
    'EUR_USD', catchup=False, default_args=default_args )

    # Define the task that prints hello with the bash operator.
    t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='FxScheduler',
    schedule_interval="*/5 * * * 1-5",
    bash_command='sh Hello.sh ',
    dag=dag
)
```

I  have used above code, **How can I mention that this task has to stop on        Friday 9 pm and again it has to start on sunday 9 pm?.**

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can refer this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression).

Schedule should be "*/5 * * * 0-5".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have another issue and couldn't find any solution, could you please help with that . How to set a dependency between two different dags tasks. If you have any sample code could you please help me.

Comment: @sai Hello sai, 
Actually I don'k know about setting dependency for two dags.
But I know that dag means a flow of job.
If you set dependency each task, you should to configure such tasks in a dag.

Answer (score 0):

This website is really helpful , https://crontab.guru/
maybe you can get idea for this ? */5 21 * * 5,6,0

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have another issue and couldn't find any solution, could you please help with that . How to set a dependency between two different dags tasks. If you have any sample code could you please help me.

Comment: I would like to help but I myself is a beginner. You can register to this dedicated airflow community https://gitter.im/apache/incubator-airflow . I am sure you can find someone to help you answer your questions regarding airflow.

Comment: You might also find this helpful @sai https://airflow.apache.org/tutorial.html#setting-up-dependencies